# All mime types integration in Google Drive UI Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

The API Manager of Google Drive API, Under UI Integration of (https://console.developers.google.com)

I want to get my app to be integrated to (all types) file type including unrecognized. The app is to display its meta data of every user selected file.

For Default MIME Types I have put

```
*/*
```

and Default File Extensions I have put

```
* //(which is error)
```

How do I get it accomplished?

Comment: Do you have the `importing` box checked?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are [supported MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) that are specific to Google Apps and Google Drive which means that integrating ALL mime types is not possible.

You may want to check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#drive_integration) to get started integrating with the Drive UI. It was stated that,

> you'll need to specify the **Open URL** for your app, and your preferences on how users create and open files with the app. Also, you can select from optional features like support for multiple file selection and Google doc import.

Please do also note on the given warning:

> Do not select *Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent screen when users open my application from Google Drive*. This feature is deprecated. All authorization requests must be initiated by the application.

You may want to also check the following references and see if it will help you:

- [Google Drive Integration](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/drive)
- [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).The advanced Drive service allows you to use the [Google Drive web API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) in Apps Script.